# Find a quadrature rule that is exact for all polynomials of degree 2 or less

Tags: numerical-methods

Where am I going wrong?
I want to prove that it's accurate for deg 2 polynomials or less and my answer doesn't suggest that? Any tips on where I'm wrong ? Ive attached an image of my work below!

[image]

Comment: Please try to type your formulas, it makes your question better accessible. Also, it may serve as a review of your calculations, thus enabling to find errors before you need to actually ask the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your principal problem is that you want to find parameters for
$$
\int_0^1f(x)dx=w_0f(x_0)+w_1f(1)
$$
but your following equations are for
$$
\int_0^1f(x)dx=w_0f(0)+w_1f(x_0)
$$
which is the mirrored situation of the task. The solutions are related, but not identical.

---

The equation to compare coefficients to find the conditions should have been
$$
A+\frac12B+\frac13C=w_0(A+Bx_0+Cx_0^2)+w_1(A+B+C)\\
\left\{\begin{aligned}
1&=w_0+w_1\\[.5em]
\frac12&=w_0x_0+w_1\\[.5em]
\frac13&=w_0x_0^2+w_1
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
a said before, similar to the ones you found, but not identical.

Comment: Where is the point i go wrong? Is it in my formula for A, B and C ? @LutzL

Comment: Are w0 and w1 = 1/2 ? @LutzL

Comment: No, your computation for the mirrored problem is correct, you would have to mirror the solution back.

Comment: Oh I see! Such a rookie mistake now I see it in front of me. Think I over complicated things in my head. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using the two point Gauss Quadrature formula ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature/)), there is a change of interval formula. This will yield an exact answer for polynomials of degree (2n-1) = 3 in our case (and therefore degree 2 as well).

Comment: There is only one sampling point free, $x_0$, the other is fixed as $x_1=1$. Gauß would apply if both sampling points were free.